# Load image files from a folder bash script Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu and learning bash script by **googling** around. I want to know how to load image files from a folder and save it in an array in bash script.

Probably am not doing a really smart search, but if anyone knows how to do it already, can you please help?

I am planning to get the path from the command line argument, so **$1** will have the path, as far as I have read.

Thus, I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$1"
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

But the output just prints **1** file instead of all **36** files. Can you please help me here?

Note : the input am giving is of this format

```
/path/*.png
```

Comment: That glob (`/path/*.png`) has already been expanded by the shell when your script is called. You have all the filenames in `$@`. Try `echo "$@"` or `for file in "$@"` (which is the same as `for file`).

Comment: @EtanReisner please hang on. It totally worked. Could you please explain me about $@?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That glob (`/path/*.png`) has already been expanded by the shell when your script is called.

You have all the filenames in `$@` (the array of all the positional parameters to the script/function).

Try

```
echo "$@"
```

to see them or

```
for file in "$@"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

The default list for `in` is `$@` so you can use `for file; do` in place of `for file in "$@"; do` if you want.

Comment: so, can I access each file name from $f? Or is it like an array that has all the filenames? If I want to send it as an inout one by one to a command line as argument, which I want to call from this script

Comment: You can loop over each name with the sort of loop I indicated.

Comment: cool. But why dint the traditional way work, when I gave the input of this format : "/path/" ? it just printed the path again. Moreover, when I did this

"FILES = $1", #before the for loop and then

"for f in $FILES" , 

I got the error saying, "FILES : command not found". Reason?

Comment: No spaces around assignments. `FILES = $1` is seen as three words and tries to run the `FILES` command with two arguments `=` and the contents of `$1`.

Comment: Like I said when you put `/path/*` on the command line (unquoted) the shell **immediately** expanded it into the filenames and passed **those** to your script. Your script never saw the `*`. When you use `/path/` there isn't a glob to expand and so your script gets that literal string as an argument.